# ruby on rails: multiple insertion SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error:

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I need to do a multiple insertion in the database.It shows me an error all the time

Single insertion works perfect:

```
CONN = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

irb(main):271:0> inserts.push'(1,2,3,4,5,6)'
=> ["(1,2,3,4,5,6)"]

sql="INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"

irb(main):276:0> CONN.execute sql
   (32.3ms)  INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6)
=> []
```

Multiple insertions do not work at all:

```
irb(main):272:0> inserts.push'(7,8,9,10,11,12)'
=> ["(1,2,3,4,5,6)", "(7,8,9,10,11,12)"]

irb(main):278:0>sql="INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
=> "INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6), (7,8,9,10,11,12)"

irb(main):279:0> CONN.execute sql
   (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6), (7,8,9,10,11,12)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: INSERT INTO signals_rmas (groupsnorm_id, arraydb_id, probeset_id,signal,updated_at,created_at) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6), (7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

What is the problem? How can I insert multiple records as a time in sql?(create record)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SQLite doesn't support inserting multiple records.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/199712

Comment: yep. It is still limited up to 500 records.